# Unable to add Preferences.xml (Android Preferences in XML)

Tags: android, preferences, android-preferences, android-xml

Hopefully, this is a newbie question with a quick answer...

I am attempting to add a simple preferences file in a new Android project (New -> Android XML File), but it doesn't appear to be working correctly.

There is no root element to choose from when I select the Preference type layout.  If I press Finish, it doesn't do anything.  See screenshot below.

Thanks,
wTs

[image]

Comment: What version of ADT plugin do you use? I'm on 0.9.9 and the selection works as a charm. Probably you just need to update the plugin?

Comment: Same version, no luck.  I can copy and paste a preferences.xml file from another project - just can't create one from scratch.

Comment: Strange.. what eclipse version? I'm on 3.6.1

Comment: Hmmm..... 3.5.2.  I'm finding that even if I copy a preferences file from elsewhere, I can't seem to see it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a normal xml file to the project /res/xml/ folder and add your content to the file as usual. Should work just great. Eclipse detects it as a preference file once you have added the preference-xml and saved it.

Comment: That's essentially what I did - it's just annoying that the "built-in" method doesn't work.

Comment: It's odd, though - it wouldn't find the reference, repeatedly.  I "refreshed" my import statements, and suddenly it found it.  Geesh.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a root element in the selection screen. Just replace whatever eclipse generates with what you want.

Comment: I would, if only Eclipse would generate something.  :)  The dialog just sits there...

Comment: Don't choose preference, choose something else.

Answer (score 1):

try refreshing the folder that the file is supposed to be in (in your example res/xml).